# What kind of geometric curve is this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-geometry, curves, control-theory, optimal-control

I am working on an optimal control problem,more specifically on minimum-time control under input constraint $|u(t)| \leq 1$, and I need to figure out the commutation curve of a bang-bang control (so $u(t)=\pm 1$). I know that for the double integrator :

$\dot{x}_1=x_2$

$\dot{x}_2=u$

the commutation curve is simply given by $x_1(t)=\pm x_2(t)^2+c$ so it's a family of parabolas. In my problem I have :

$\dot{x}_1=x_2$

$\dot{x}_2=-\omega^2 x_1-2\gamma x_2 + u$

where $\gamma,\omega >0$.

The solution of this system (with suitable initial conditions i.e. $x(0)=(0 \ 0)^T$ ) is :

$x_1(t)= -e^{-\gamma t}-\gamma te^{-\gamma t} \pm 1$

$x_2(t)=\gamma^2 te^{-\gamma t}$

The $\pm 1$ depends on what input I want to start with and w.l.o.g.  I can start with $u=1$.

Then, how can I write the commutation curve for these trajectories? I thought about writing :

$x_1(t)=-e^{-\gamma t}-\frac{x_2(t)}{\gamma} \pm 1$

but I don't even know if this is an actual geometric curve. This last formula comes from the fact that $x_2(t)$ is already contained in $x_1(t)$ but the constant multiple $\lambda$.

Comment: This will be given by Pontryagin's maximum principle. You will need to apply that to solve your optimal control problem.

Comment: Due to the lack of boundary conditions on the costate, I cannot express the control as $u=-sign\{\lambda(t)^TB\}$. Best I can do is $u=-sign\{\phi(x)\}$, where $\phi(x)$ is such commutation curve. Hence the question.

Comment: Then, your post seriously lacks details. What is the cost you want to minimize? Where is the curve you suggest coming from? What are those "suitable initial conditions" and what control input do you consider when computing the solution of this system? etc. etc. Please provide all the details regarding your problem.